# What algorithm determines when and where hero tokens appear?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I've noticed that most tokens appear in specific locations, as if each token type has some predefined slots on each map where it may appear (besides hero and pod drops, of course).  I've also noticed that there appears to be some algorithm governing when a particular token will appear.  For example there doesn't appear to be a way to have a more than one hero or 3 air fighters per side on most maps (with the exception of fighter squadron).
[image: Hero token]
What other factors effect the frequency, when, and where a hero token will appear?

Is it totally random, with only the rules I already mentioned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer for hero pickups:
We don't know the algorithm. It appears to be random, but it is dictated by a few rules.

1. You can't have more than one hero on your team outside of Heroes vs Villains
2. There are respawn timers on Hero pickups similar to vehicle pickups.

Long answer on vehicles:
I recently tested this in Walker Assault and confirmed a few things. The vehicle and power-up drops do, definitely, reoccur in the same locations. An AT-ST would respawn about 20 seconds after the last user dies in it (or abandons it). In Walker Assault they will spawn in certain locations depending on where the game's progress is.

There are limits to how many vehicles are available, but it depends on the map. Your team can, as an example, grab both x-wings in phase 1 of Walker Assault and make them live the entire game. If both a-wings from phase 2 survive, in phase 3 your rebel team could have 6 starships in the air at once (2 airspeeders are available in phase 3). Other game modes have a hard limit on number of vehicles and starfighters because the pickup will not regenerate until the last user dies or ditches the vehicle.

[EA recently released patch notes](http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/forums/discussion/25232/star-wars-battlefront-january-update-ps4-pc-x1) that give us a small glimpse into how it works, but we'll never really know their algorithm. They recently added a little buffer to the respawn times:

> - Starfighters pickups have a 20 second respawn delay
> - T-47 Airspeeder pickups have a 10 second respawn delay

Comment: I just noticed that as well, they are admitting there's a default timer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of knowing what's the exact algorithm, unless someone from Dice steps forward (highly unlikely) but to make the game balanced there are few rules:

1. Similarly to spawn locations, tokes appear only at certain points on the map. Otherwise the token might spawn on an unreachable location and make the game uneven, or have the opposite team overtake the middle of the map, and make the token unreachable.
2. Yes only certain amount of heroes, air and land vehicles are allowed. This is done again for the sake of fair and even game. It's not going to be much fun shooting against an army of darth Vaders, or even worse couple of Fets. So a hero token wont appear when there is already a hero or a token on the map.
3. I do believe there is a certain amount of seconds that need to pass, after a hero's death, before the token appears, but don't quote me on that, I'm not very good at finding tokens.

Comment: Did you mean to say that Boba Fett is better than Darth Vader?